# Iterating over datasets in h5 file but the changes won't be saved

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, conv-neural-network, h5py

I am trying to modify the weights of a model by applying a certain(one_hot_bit) function on the datasets in the h5 file and then load the model with the new weights. I finally figured how to apply mu function on different datasets shapes in the h5 file. The issue is that after closing the file and try to reopen it and print any dataset, the original dataset values are printed and not the modified one.
Here is the code

```
f1 = h5py.File('/content/model_weights.h5', 'r')     # open the file
for dset in traverse_datasets('/content/model_weights.h5'):
  dataset1 = np.array(hdf.get(dset))
  for x in np.nditer(dataset1, op_flags=['writeonly']):
      x[...]= one_hot_bit_val(x)
  print(dataset1)  
f1.close()
```

traverse_datasets is to find the datasets paths in the h5 file and one_hot_bit_val() is my function to modify the weights. I am printing every dataset while looping and the printed values are correct. It is when I try to reprint it again after closing the file as in here:

```
f1 = h5py.File('/content/model_weights.h5', 'r')     # open the file
dataset1 = np.array(f1.get('/conv2d_1/conv2d_1/bias:0'))
print(dataset1)
```

The dataset1 has the original values before applying the one_hot_bit function.

Comment: You are modifying the array that was created from the dataset, not the dataset itself. Review the h5py docs on how to write new values to a dataset.

Comment: I don't think using nditer` helps.  It isn't any faster than plain iteration. But it isn't the problem here.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help!

Comment: `ds = hdf.get(dset)`; `arr = ds[:]` to fetch; `ds[:] = arr` to set.